# Error al consumir mi propia API

Tags: php, json, api

Hola el error / duda que tengo es que trato de consumir mi propia y no logro tomar los datos que estoy tomando de mi JSON, se que algo esta mal por eso pido ayuda

este es el primer código, es aquí donde hago la conexión a mi API ( las variables $n y $p las obtengo de un formulario)

```
<?php 

 $n = $_POST['nombre'];
 $p = $_POST['pass'];

 $nn = urlencode($n);

$json = file_get_contents("http://localhost/APIDB/api.php? 
nombre=$nn&pass=$p");

echo $json;

 ?>
```

este es el código de mi API

```
<?php

 $n = $_GET['nombre'];
 $p = $_GET['pass']; 

$cnx = new mysqli("localhost","root", "" , "empresa");

$res=$cnx->query("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE nombre = '$n' and pass 
= '$p'");

$datos=array();

  foreach ($res as $row) {

$datos[]=$row;

}

 echo json_encode($datos); 

 ?>
```

Ahora lo que pasa es que debo consumir mi API de esta manera, a manera de link es para una tarea, luego me surgen diferentes dudas como por ejemplo como puedo obtener cada dato del JSON en mi primero código a manera de que luego pueda convertirlos en variables para luego usarlas.

Otra cosa así como tengo ambos código lo único que ocurre es que me imprime todo el JSON pero no se donde ocurre eso, es decir estoy perdido al usar dos archivos.

Espero me puedan ayudar les agradecería mucho, soy nuevo usando json_decode y json_encode desconozco un poco sus diferencias, si me sugieren una manera distinta de hacerlo lo agradecería o si me dicen mis errores también los agradecería.

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar decirte que no es una buena práctica enviar una contraseña por GET por mucho que sea tu propia API y menos así a la ligera, sin SSL, etc.

Además indicarte que eso es vulnerable ante inyecciones SQL, pues no filtras ninguna de ambas variables, y la contraseña también puede contener caracteres como '&' y otros, filtres o no en front-end previamente.

No obstante, volviendo a tu pregunta:
En primer lugar, al principio del documento que devuelve json, debes poner:

```
header('Content-Type: text/json');
```

Para que sea interpretado como JSON, al hacerlo en PHP, puede no darte ese problema, pero por ejemplo, si utilizas tecnologías como Ajax en front-end, si el formato es **text/html** (por defecto), en lugar de **text/json**, no podrás utilizar los datos de las variables, ya que no lo leerá como objeto json.

Para utilizar lo que te devuelve **file_get_contents** como un array en PHP, es decir, en este caso "transladar un array de un lugar a otro", puedes utilizar la función **json_decode**, que es contraria a la de **json_encode** que ya utilizas.

Quedando:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://localhost/APIDB/api.php?nombre=$nn&pass=$p"));
```

De esta forma, **$json** será equivalente al array **$datos** del otro código.

En tu código, si no existe usuario, te dará error, si hay más de uno, no funcionará como es debido. Aquí lo adecuado sería hacer un simple **fetch_assoc** para obtener una sola fila, y hacerlo solo si haces un **num_rows** y la cantidad es igual a 1.

Ya para concluir decirte que por favor, seas consistente con el uso de comillas dobles y simples. Siempre defenderé que no se usen comillas dobles en PHP bajo ningún concepto (con muy pocas excepciones), ya que simplemente es más ineficiente.
Otra cosa es evitar usar el español como nombre de variables y otros.

Y sobre todo, cuida los inputs, nunca querrás que alguien malicioso entre en tu página y haga una inyección SQL.

P.D: La forma de ver el contenido de un array en PHP, por si te resulta útil dado que haces:

```
echo $json;
```

Y ahora **$json** será un array, podrás verlo haciendo:

```
print_r($json);
```

Comment: Algo que podrías agregar es que tampoco es recomendable que guarde las contraseñas sin encriptar